# Контекстуально-ситуативный анализ - определение понятия

Tags: общие-вопросы, анализ-текста

Кажется, есть такой метод анализа текста. Не могу найти его определение.
На одном сайте http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/1847717/ есть небольшая конкретизация метода, но она не даёт понимания сути:
"Контекстуально-ситуационный анализ (одна единица в разных контекстах)"
Какая единица имеется в виду? Может ли это быть, например, мотив/образ/лексема? Тогда суть анализа в том, чтобы посмотреть, как этот мотив/образ/лексема видоизменяется, переосмысливается в разных текстах?
В общем, помогите, пожалуйста, те, кто разбирается. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контекстуально-ситуативный анализ - анализ языкового материала (на фонетическом, морфологическом, лексическом, синтаксическом, семантическом уровнях) в зависимости от ситуации общения.

Контекст ситуации может быть описан путем рассмотрения:
а) экономических, религиозных и других социальных структур общества, членами которых являются участники речевого акта;
б) типов речевых отрезков в виде монолога, повествования, декламации, объяснения;
в) изменения числа, возраста и пола участников, с указанием читающего, говорящего и пишущего;
г) типов речевых функций, таких, как муштра, приказания, подробные указания, социальная лесть, проклятие, восхваление, обман, общественный гнет и принуждение, речевые соглашения.

Контекстуализм подчеркивает зависимость смысла и значения единиц языка от включенности в синтаксические, семантические и прагматические системы, от ситуации употребления, культуры и истории.

Другими словами,это анализ, например,не одного предложения, а предложения как части высказывания, речевой ситуации(тип речи, стиль речи, кто говорит, когда, зачем)

Суть его в том, чтобы посмотреть, как единица языка работает в разных ситуациях. Одно и то же слово, сказанное ребёнку и взрослому, образованным человеком и малограмотным, в 19 и 20 веке, различается.